# Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove an Inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, radicals, extreme-value-theorem

Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $$\frac{1}{9}<\sqrt{66}-8<\frac{1}{8}$$

I really don't know how to use the mean value theorem for this as $$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ I would give more but I'm really stuck. Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not seeing it myself.  MVT says that somewhere in between 64 and 81 the derivative is $\frac 1 {17}$,   you have the derivative monotonically decreases from $\frac 1 {16}$ to $\frac 1 {18}$.  Actually I see an answer, just not using MVT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sqrt{x}$ satisfies all the conditions of MVT on [64, 66]. So there exists some c ∈ (64,66) such that $\frac{\sqrt{66} - \sqrt{64}}{66 - 64}$ = $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}$.
So $\sqrt{66} - 8 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$. We know $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a strictly decreasing function on (64, 66), thus for any $n ∈ (64, 66)$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{66}}$ < $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ < $\frac{1}{\sqrt{64}} = \frac{1}{8}.$ You can combine these, and that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{66}}$ > $\frac{1}{\sqrt{81}}$ = $\frac{1}{9}$, to finish the proof - can you see how?

Comment: Ok, so if I follow:

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I assume this might be a typo, but do you mean $\frac{1}{\sqrt{66}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{81}}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry - that was a typo. Just edited it

Comment: Alright, let me see if I actually do follow: from your two equations we have $\frac{1}{8}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>\frac{1}{9}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{66}-8$ Q.E.D.?

Comment: @Copywright yes!

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the catch there. Just fixed that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not using MVT, you have between 64 and 81 the derivative is monotonically decreasing from $\frac 1 {16}$ to $\frac 1 {18}$.

This means taking a linear approximation at $x=64$,  for values in $(64,81)$
$$\frac 1 {18}(x-64)+8< \sqrt {x}<\frac 1 {16}(x-64)+8$$
plugging in $x=66$ gets you there.  Not sure where MVT is supposed to come into this

Comment: Ok, I can see how this works. Really the difficulty of the question is using the MVT. Thanks anyways tho